# org.hibernate.QueryException: not all parameters have been set

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following exception error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set: [c]  
[UPDATE  EtudeCredit e SET e.avisfin=:c WHERE e.codeEc=:idEc]
```

My code is::

```
public EtudeCredit updateavisfin(Integer id, String avisfint) {
      Query d= entityManager.createQuery("UPDATE  EtudeCredit e SET e.avisfin=:c WHERE                e.codeEc=:idEc");  
        d.setParameter("idEc",id).executeUpdate();
         d.setParameter("c",avisfint).executeUpdate();
        return (EtudeCredit) d.getSingleResult();}
```

Any help? what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should call `executeUpdate()` once, when both parameters are set. Now you call it twice.

```
d.setParameter("idEc",id);
d.setParameter("c",avisfint);
d.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: I have changed executeupdate as you said I have now : not supported for DML OPERATION

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to update twice before setting your two parameters. You have to first set the parameters and then execute the update:

```
d.setParameter("idEc",id);
d.setParameter("c",avisfint);
d.executeUpdate();
```

Alos, update statements have no "persistence object results", so you can't issue a "getSingleResult" on it. You have to create another query (a SELECT statement) if you want to retrieve a result after your update.